# Retrieve instance metadata using IMDSv2 on AWS Windows EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

I have the following bash script to retrieve instance metadata (IMDSv2) on Linux server:

```
TOKEN=$(curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" 2>&1 null)

instance_id=$(curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

which is referred from the AWS documentation site [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html). However, it does not have information for Windows EC2 instances using power shell cmd.

What is the equivalent IMDSv2 cmd for EC2 on Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the above IMDSv2 on Windows EC2 server, use the following cmd:

```
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds" = "21600"}

$instance_id = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token}

Write-Host "Instance ID: $instance_id"
```

This will print the output as: `Instance ID: i-0fe2f8ed980984`